# populating KendoComboBox with list

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

according to the KendoComboBox documentation, the way to populate it is as follows:

```
 $("#teamName").kendoComboBox({
                dataTextField: "text",
                dataValueField: "value",                
                    dataSource: [
                  { text: "Item1", value: "1" },
                  { text: "Item2", value: "2" }
                ]
            })
```

but now I have a list in the view which is stored in Model.Teams.  Can someone suggest a good way to populate the combobox with the data in Model.Teams?

eg: I'm wanting to do something like:

```
...
 var model = (function () {
                return {
                    Teams: '@Model.Teams'
                }});
...
...
dataSource: [
         for (var i = 0; i < model.Teams.Count; i++) {
            { text: "model.Team[i]", value: "model.Team[i]" },
         }
         ]
```

but it does not like the syntax of this.

Comment: Whats the Team object look like?
Basically its just as below but with the text and value fields named after the team members with the info you want (ID,Name or similar probably)

dataSource: Model.Teams

Comment: it's just a list of string.  Have updated the OP with more on what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle with what you have so far?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6nawtsgs/  . The teams variable I created is just a demo, in reality the teams variable might have many entries which is why I want to do it with a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to use the MVC, then you should be able to follow along on [Kendo's Demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/combobox/index) page.

I updated your [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6nawtsgs/2/) to do this all within the JavaScript.

```js
var teams = ["A team", "B team"];
var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource();

$("#teamName").kendoComboBox({
  dataTextField: "text",
  dataValueField: "value",
  dataSource: ds
});

//Can use either method to add items to the data source
if (true) { //Change my to false, same results!
  for (var i = 0; i < teams.length; i++) {
    ds.add({
      text: teams[i],
      value: teams[i]
    });
  }
} else {
  ds.data(teams.map(function(team) {
    return { text: team, value: team };
  }));
}
```

```html
<link href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<input id="teamName" name="team" placeholder="Team name" style="width:300px">
```